# Compiler define for Design Time package or code to check for execution in IDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Are there any compiler defines or functions/constants/variables that can be used to tell whether some code is being built for a design time package or is being executed from inside the IDE?

We have some code hooks that we setup in the initialization of a unit which is part of a package. We don't want this code to be executed when installing the package in the IDE, only when it's running as part of our application.

For now I have added a compiler define to the design time package which strips out the code but I was wondering if there was a built in compiler define that indicates that this is part of a design time package or if there is some function/constant that can be checked to see if the code is running inside the IDE. Similar to the old `if csDesigning in ComponentState then` that people use from inside components.

Comment: Sorry. Misread your question - my fault, not yours. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there any compiler defines or functions/constants/variables that can be used to tell whether some code is being built for a design time package or is being executed from inside the IDE?

No.

> We have some code hooks that we setup in the initialization of a unit which is part of a package. We don't want this code to be executed when installing the package in the IDE, only when it's running as part of our application.

Then that code does not belong in the unit's `initialization` section at all.  Move it to a separate function that your application code can call during its startup.

> For now I have added a compiler define to the design time package which strips out the code

That implies that your design-time package is directly compiling your run-time code, which it should not be doing at all.  Run-time code and design-time code need to be in separate packages.  Run-time code does not belong in a design-time package, and design-time code does not belong in a run-time package.

> I was wondering if there was a built in compiler define that indicates that this is part of a design time package

There is not.  However, if you create separate run-time and design-time packages (as you should be), then your hook code belongs in the run-time package only.  The design-time package can `require` the run-time package (so it has access to your run-time components), and the run-time package can expose a global variable that the design-time package can set.  The run-time code can then ignore whatever it needs to ignore if that variable is set.

Comment: Of course, the runtime and designtime parts should be separate. In this case, this is a "working" library. We have a designtime package and no runtime package. The units are included in the main application. While not very elegant, this helps practically because we often make changes to the internal workings of this code and updating packages wastes time with a large team.

Comment: "*We have a designtime package and no runtime package. The units are included in the main application.*" A design-time package should only be used for implementing IDE editors and component registrations. Anything the application uses must be in the application itself or in a run-time package that the application uses (and shares with the design-time package). Such code does not belong in the design-time package directly. So, under this model, it doesn't make sense for your code to need to detect design-time unless it is in a run-time package that the design-time package uses.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should follow the practice as written in [Remy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43507852), but real life code tends to be more complicated.

There is a way to check whether package is loaded by the IDE or not, by checking whether command line parameter contains `bds.exe`. It is rather crude solution, but it works fine nonetheless.

You can make a function that will perform the check.

```
function IsDesignTime: Boolean;
begin
  Result := ParamStr(0).EndsWith('\bds.exe', True);
end;
```

If you need to call that function within code that is not only called during application initialization, and where performance matters, you can initialize Boolean flag and avoid parsing the command line every time you do the check.

```
function IsDesignTime: Boolean;

implementation

var
  DesignTime: Boolean;

function IsDesignTime: Boolean;
begin
  Result := DesignTime;
end;

initialization

  DesignTime := ParamStr(0).EndsWith('\bds.exe', True);

end.
```

**Note:** Initializing Boolean flag depends on unit initialization order, so make sure to put that function in some base unit that does not have circular unit dependencies that may change initialization order.

Because class constructors inside that unit will run before unit initialization section, `DesignTime` will not be initialized at that time and you will have to move `IsDesignTime` to another unit if you need to call the function from any class constructor inside that unit.

In such case you can also move initialization to class constructor, but depending on the code it may be harder to guarantee calling order of class constructors and you also need to ensure that appropriate class constructor is called in the first place.

Comment: This is actually a really clever solution.